# Shopping cart not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

Code for the shopping cart:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Shopping Cart</title>
    <script src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Shopping Cart</h1>

    <div>
        <ul>
            <li><a class="add-to-cart" href="#" data-name="Apple" data-price="1.22">Apple $1.22</a></li>
            <li><a class="add-to-cart" href="#" data-name="Banana" data-price="1.33">Banana $1.33 </a></li>
            <li><a class="add-to-cart" href="#" data-name="Shoe" data-price="22.33">Shoe $22.33</a></li>
            <li><a class="add-to-cart" href="#" data-name="Frisbee" data-price="5.22">Frisbee $5.22</a></li>
        </ul>
        <form>
            <button id="clear-cart">Clear Cart</button>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div>
        <ul id="show-cart">
            <!-- -->
        </ul>
    </div>
    <script>

        $(".add-to-cart").click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var name = $(this).attr("data-name");
            var price = Number($(this).attr("data-price"));

            addItemToCart(name, price, 1);
            displayCart();
        });

        function displayCart() {
            console.log("*** Display Cart ***");
            var cartArray = listCart();
            var output = "";
            for (var i in cartArray) {
                output += "<li>"+cartArray[i].name+" "+cartArray[i].count+"</li>"
            }
            $("#show-cart").html(output);
        }

        displayCart();

        // ************************************************************
        // Shopping Cart Functions

        var cart = [];
        var Item = function(name, price, count) {
            this.name = name
            this.price = price
            this.count = count
        };

        function addItemToCart(name, price, count) {
            for (var i in cart) {
                if (cart[i].name === name) {
                    cart[i].count += count;
                    return;
                }
            }
            var item = new Item(name, price, count);
            cart.push(item);
            saveCart();
        }

        function removeItemFromCart(name) { // Removes one item
            for (var i in cart) {
                if (cart[i].name === name) {
                    cart[i].count --;
                    if (cart[i].count === 0) {
                        cart.splice(i, 1);
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
            saveCart();
        }

        function removeItemFromCartAll(name)  { // Removes all item name 
            for (var i in cart) {
                if (cart[i].name === name) {
                    cart.splice(i, 1);
                    break;
                }
            }
            saveCart();
        }



        function clearCart() {
            cart = [];
            saveCart();
        } 

        function countCart() { // --> return total count 
            var totalCount = 0;
            for (var i in cart) {
                totalCount += cart[i].count;
            }

            return totalCount;
        }

        console.log( countCart() );

        function totalCart() { // --> return total cost 
            var totalCost = 0;
            for (var i in cart) {
                totalCost += cart[i].price;
            }
            return totalCost;
        }

        console.log( totalCart() );

        function listCart() {  // --> array of Items 
            var cartCopy = [];
            for (var i in cart) {
                var item = cart[i];
                var itemCopy = {};
                for (var p in item) {
                    itemCopy[p] = item[p];
                }
                cartCopy.push(itemCopy);
            }
            return cartCopy;
        }

        console.log( listCart() );

        function saveCart() {
            localStorage.setItem("shoppingCart", JSON.stringify(cart));
        }

        function loadCart() {
            cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("shoppingCart"));  
        }

        loadCart();




        // Shopping Cart Functions (complete)
        // ************************************************************

    </script>
```

I have this persistent error where on reload, it does not save the changes that I have made. So, for example, I have ordered 2 Frisbees worth some amount (for now that doesn't matter), but when refresh it, and click to order some product, the shopping cart doesn't save the changes, even though it is supposed to. I am not sure where the problem lies, so I have pasted the whole thing in here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never save the item to localstorage when your increment the count of an item already in your cart.

```
    function addItemToCart(name, price, count) {
        for (var i in cart) {
            if (cart[i].name === name) {
                cart[i].count += count;
                //need to do this here too.
                saveCart();
                //
                return;
            }
        }
        var item = new Item(name, price, count);
        cart.push(item);
        saveCart();
    }
```

Otherwise it will only save the cart to localstorage when adding a new item, so until then the incremented items aren't saved into storage.

Comment: Thanks. I was really stuck with the problem!